# How to remove comments in chunk-vendors.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

a little strange question, but how to remove comments from the file chunk-vendors.js? I mean, there are automatically placed licenses and other information about plugins, including the vue, vuex, vue-router.

Is there any parameter responsible for this? I’m tired of removing these lines manually after each build

I use vue-cli

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming Vue CLI 3 or newer, this is handled by the minimizer's (`terser`) [output options](https://github.com/terser/terser#output-options). Specifically, set `output.comments=false` to exclude comments from the minified output.

Edit [`vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) to include:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.minimizer('terser').tap((args) => {
      args[0].terserOptions.output = {
        ...args[0].terserOptions.output,
        comments: false  // exclude all comments from output
      }
      return args
    })
  }
}
```